# Flask- multiple paginations on same page

Tags: python, flask

Currently, I paginate one object using

```
articles = g.user.articles().paginate(page, ARTICLES_PER_PAGE, False)
```

and in view

```
@app.route('/index/<int:page>')
```

I'd like to paginate several objects on the same page. How can I do that? Thanks.

Comment: Your question is not clear. What you mean with "paginate several objects on the same page"?

Comment: You mean with separate page values for each pagination? @app.route('/index/<int:page1>/<int:page2>') ???

Comment: Sorry for ambiguity, I'm not a native speaker. I have several tables on the same page and want to paginate all of them. So all tables show only part of its data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you want to page them individually (that is, the user can for example go to page 3 of one list, and page 15 of another list) you have to adjust your `@app.route` to also remember all of the current positions of the other lists, like so:

```
@app.route('/index/<int:page_of_list1>/<int:page_of_list2>/<int:page_of_list3>')
def index(page_of_list1, page_of_list2, page_of_list3):
```

And then use those positions to determine the query on your data (inside `index()`):

```
   list1 = g.user.articles().paginate(page_of_list1, ARTICLES_PER_PAGE, False)
   list2 = some_other_query.paginate(page_of_list2, ARTICLES_PER_PAGE, False)
   list3 = yet_another_query.paginate(page_of_list3, ARTICLES_PER_PAGE, False)
```

If you always want to use the SAME position for every list (so a that goes to page 3 of one list, is *always* on page 3 of list2 and list3), you can just use the latter part of the code and use `page` in all the queries.

*Please rename these `list_...` variables to something more useful based on what's stored inside them*

Comment: This works if you know the number of objects you want to paginate through. How could you do this with a variable number of objects?

Answer (score 0):

You can do it easily, treating each table separated.

```
articles = g.user.articles().paginate(page, ARTICLES_PER_PAGE, False)
other_objects = YourModel.query.paginate(page, ARTICLES_PER_PAGE, False)
```

Does it work for you?